# Is dataframe.colums a Spark action?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

If not, there is no action method in the following code, but `"./demo.json"` is read once.

```
val x = spark.read.json("./demo.json")
println(x.columns)
```

Answer (score 0):

`dataframe.columns` is not an action per se, but it needs to get the schema of your dataframe.  Depending on the file format, this needs a file-scan (json, csv). With other file formats like parquet, the columns can be extracted from the meta-data, so no actual file scan is needed

Comment: So there is negligible computional cost for csv, parquet or sql table data. For json data,  it's like a one-partition action method?

Answer (score 0):

`spark.read.json` is an action that reads all your data to infer the schema (unless you specify it manually). Hence `x.columns` will not trigger any action.

According to the [latest documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader) (click on json):

> This function goes through the input once to determine the input
>   schema. If you know the schema in advance, use the version that
>   specifies the schema to avoid the extra scan.